# Auto-Implemented Properties Vs. Public Properties in binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, set, accessor

Recently I have found out that in my binding, the second simplified method is working just as good as the second one. Since I have always done it using the first, I want to know what could be the reason to chose one or the other.

**Public method with a dummy Private variable**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyDeviceInfo> DiscoveredDevicesList
{
    get
    {
        return _DiscoveredDevicesList;
    }
    set
    {
        _DiscoveredDevicesList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DiscoveredDevicesList");
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<MyDeviceInfo> _DiscoveredDevicesList;
```

**Auto-Implemented Properties**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyDeviceInfo> DiscoveredDevicesList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does your second version also work when you are replacing the collection with a new collection? Since that is the difference between the two. If you are using binding to keep your UI (or something else) up-to-date of the *contents* of the collection, then they will both work.

Comment: This is a very interesting point. However I need a bit of clearing up here. When you say "replacing with a new collection" what exactly you mean? In regards to the second sentence, isn't the purpose of binding to keep the UI up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers primarily to the `ObservableCollection<T>` properties. The `Public method with a dummy Private variable` need to specify the DataContext via XAML, for example:

`ObservableCollection<T>`

```
public class ViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _myCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> MyCollection
    {
       get
       {
           return _myCollection;
       }

       set
       {
           _myCollection = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("MyCollection");
       }
    }
}
```

`XAML`

```
<!-- Set the DataContext in XAML -->
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" /> <!-- Or any other control -->
</Grid>
```

Work with collection in code-behind like this:

```
ViewModel MyViewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel;

MyViewModel.MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

MyViewModel.MyCollection.Add(new Person()
{
    Age = 22,
    Name = "Nick",
});
```

In this case, if the collection would have been with automatic property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> MyCollection
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Then `Binding` would not work, namely the it would not update the property collection. But, if you set the `DataContext` in code-behind:

```
this.DataContext = MyViewModel;
```

The `Binding` will work with automatic property.

Answer (score 1):

Using the auto-implemented property, if you set the `DiscoveredDevicesList` property to a entirely new `ObservableCollection`, your view will have no way of knowing. However, if all you are doing is adding/removing/reordering items in a single instance of the `ObservableCollection`, then this will work fine because the view is also binding to the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged) interface (which is implemented by `ObservableCollection`) on `DiscoveredDevicesList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind auto-properties but any changes you make to the property from code won't show up in the UI. In general any object being used for data binding should include change notification and so should not use auto-properties.

Comment: Do note that he is using an `ObservableCollection<T>`, so what you are saying is not directly true.